# c++ function passes bad parameter

Tags: c++, ifstream

I have this function as constructor:

```
Graph::Graph(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream file(filename);
    file >> vertexNum_;
    edgeNum_ = 0;
    int edges;
    file >> edges;
    for(int i = 0; i < edges; edges++)
    {
        int s,e;
        file >> s;
        file >> e;
        if(!AddEdge(s,e)){
            std::cout << "Bad file!";
            break;
        }
    }
    file.close();
}
```

When I call from main `Graph g("test.in");` it gives me Segfault because in the function parameter `filename` is empty string (shown in debugger). I'm using QtCreator.

Any ideas where the problem is?

Comment: Check if your file is [opened](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/is_open/) before using your ifstream

Comment: Do you have any overloaded constructors? like one taking a pointer?

Comment: Declare your constructor as `Graph::Graph(const std::string& filename)` instead. It will avoid string copy and some problems that could produce.

Comment: If you're sure that `filename` is empty then try forcibly convert `filename` into `std::string`. `Graph g(std::string("test.in"));` This might work.

Comment: I have overloaded constructor `Graph(int n)`

Comment: Which compiler do you use? GCC complains since `ifstream` doesn't have a matching constructor. It does have one that accepts an `char const*` though.

Comment: Also are you sure that the debugger doesn't miss data that is optimized away? What do you get if you do a printout of `filename` in the beginning of the function?

Comment: Try `std::string str="test.in"; Graph g(str);`.

Comment: Turning `string filename` into `const string & filename` works, thanks!